# Cannot switch offline a specific CPU

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu

I am trying to switch some CPU in my system by `echo "0" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuN/online`. `cpuN` indicates to a specific CPU number.

My system have 48 CPUs and I successfully switched offline cpu1 to cpu46. When I was switching off cpu47, I get a strange error as follows.

```
echo "0" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu47/online
bash: echo: write error: No space left on device
```

What is the possible issue in my system?

Comment: Just to confirm: you're trying to power off cpu47 alone, not *after* disabling all other CPU cores?

Comment: @MarcusMüller cpu0 can't be turned offline, so not *all* other CPU cores are turned off :p

Comment: @JaromandaX ah, good to know, but I was thinking in a similar direction: seeing that cpu0 wasn't touched, I was assuming that there might be a driver that, e.g. for interrupt/handling balancing reasons (e.g. high-rate NIC) would require two CPU cores to be available.

Comment: Do you use cpusets? The ENOSPC error smells like you are offlining the last CPU of a cpuset

Comment: No I don't use cpusets